# Implement Ajax to load HTML depending on radio button value

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hello I am really new to AJAX PHP and JQuery so any suggestion is really apprecciated.
I have an HTML page with a form, in this form I have 3 radio buttons with 3 values. My objective is to print some HTML depeding on this values.

For example if I select the radio button 2 (value=2) so -->

```
echo <input type="text">
echo <input type="text">
```

I managed to print the value in a empty div under the buttons but I don't know how to generate code with the $_POST variable (I tried to iclude the action page but it didn't work)

HTML:

```
<div class="hide">
  <input type="radio" name="cat_2" value="1">One
  <input type="radio" name="cat_2" value="2">Two
  <input type="radio" name="cat_2" value="3">Three
</div>
<div id="response"></div>
<?php include 'gen.php'; ?> //my failed test
```

JQuery:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.hide input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
                var value= $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax_page.php",
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {ajax: 1, value: value},
                    success: function (response) {
                    $('#response').text(value);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

ajax_page.php just to test the value:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    echo $_POST['value'];
} else {
    echo "Nothing to Show";
}
?>
```

I don't know if I was enough clear, **any idea** would be really helpful I don't even know what to search for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gen.php` is run before the webpage is sent to the browser. You won't be able to access any return variables or information from the ajax call because the `gen.php` code will already have run. `gen.php` will need to have all the information BEFORE it runs/the browser loads the page. If you need code to run AFTER the browser loads the page, you'll have to do that on your `ajax_page.php`.

Just a hint for your ajax_page. You should avoid using the supervariables directly and filter the input first (to prevent malicious or accidental problems). Something like this:

```
   if($value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "value", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){
        echo $value;
    } else {
        echo "Nothing to Show";
    }
```

You should capture the error from the ajax call as well and log it to the console (or present it to the user). Here is how you can log it to the console.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hide input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var value= $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax_page.php",
            type: 'post',
            data: {ajax: 1, value: value},
            success: function (response) {

                // Loop to output repeated HTML
                var output = "";
                for (i = 0; i < response; i++) {
                    // Put the HTML in here for example you could create the output:
                    output = output + "<p>test</p>";
                }
                // and then display it
                $('#response').html(output);
            },
            error: function (response){
               console.log(response)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but the code is not working. I included the ajax_page.php under the form but it always says Nothing to Show even if I click on radio buttons.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: In your javascript, under success, you have `$('#response').text(value);` that should be `$('#response').text(response);`

Comment: See remarks inside answer for more code / javascript code.

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle showing the above code working: https://jsfiddle.net/jeffincanada/8ogcmzx2/  (I am using my domain for hosting the ajax_page.php that you have above).

Comment: Try replacing the ajax_page.php code with my code above. It's working perfectly through the jsfiddle, and on my server. So I would assume you have a typo somewhere that got put into the javascript or the php after you posted the question (while you were working on it). The javascript presented above, works with the php presented above (in this answer). I'm about to hop on a plane -- so I won't be able to see this for awhile. I'll be at a hotel with wifi -- but I'm going into the remote north tomorrow and will not have internet.

Comment: It works showing the value in the DIV but I was interested in including the php file under the form (where is now the div) and show the value from it with echo and not with Javascript text. Sorry if I don't speak fluent English

Comment: @FatRat -- that's okay -- I only speak English! (So you got me beat on that!).  You cannot include any of the information you receive back from the AJAX call in your PHP :(. The PHP runs BEFORE the page loads -- and it doesn't rerun again.

Comment: thank you then. Do you have any suggestion?? I have to generate some Html code X times (the value) and for doing that I thought I could get the Value via Ajax and with Php create a for, but if it's not Possibile can you advise me another solution?

Comment: You could use javascript to run the loop and create the HTML that's needed... (see edits in answer... there's a new for loop inside the AJAX success)

Comment: I also added an example of how you might output the html